# How to make a triangle of x's in python?

Tags: python, function, geometry

How would I write a function that produces a triangle like this:

```
    x
   xx
  xxx
 xxxx
xxxxx
```

Let's say the function is `def triangle(n)`, the bottom row would have `n` amount of x's

All I know how to do is make a box:

```
n = 5
for k in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print('x', end='')
    print()
```

Comment: you should try something yourself first, instead of just posting the question. This counts your previous question as well.

Comment: Two hints: Python's [string methods](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) and the fact that your triangle is right-justified text.

Comment: A different hint: you can multiply strings by integers to repeat them (`'a'*3 == 'aaa'`).  How many spaces and how many xs are there in each line?

Comment: Hmm, okay, I'll try something.  I assume I should use a while loop somewhere in it.  I would normally give it more of a go, but I've been up since 5 am cramming and the test is in the morning, so I'm frantic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dude It's super easy:

```
def triangle(n):
    for i in range(1, n +1):
        print ' ' * (n - i) + 'x' * i
```

Or even:

```
def triangle(n):
    for i in range(1, n +1):
        print ('x' * i).rjust(n, ' ')
```

output for `triangle(5)`:

```
    x
   xx
  xxx
 xxxx
xxxxx
```

Dont just copy this code without comprehending it, try and learn how it works. Usually good ways to practice learning a programming language is trying different problems and seeing how you can solve it. I recommend [this site](http://projecteuler.net/), because i used it a lot when i first started programming.

And also, dont just post your homework or stuff like that if you dont know how to do it, only if you get stuck. First try thinking of lots of ways you think you can figure something out, and if you dont know how to do a specific task just look it up and learn from it.

Comment: I downvoted your question because it seems as if you havent tried very hard

Comment: I'm sorry, I usually wouldn't, but I'm really desperate right now as my final is in about 7 hours.  I don't just copy it, I do try to learn how it works after I see it, because it won't be asked in this exact way on my test, so I need to know how it works.  Anyways, thank you!

Comment: Awesome, i hope you do well on you test :P

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small change you could make to your program

```
n = 5
for k in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print('x' if j+k >= n-1 else ' ', end='')
    print()
```

It's not a very good way to do it though. You should think about printing a whole like at a time using something like this

```
n = 5
for k in range(n):
    i = ???
    j = ???
    print(' '*i+'x'*j)
```

You just need to work out `i` and `j`

Answer (score 0):

```
hight = 5
for star in range(hight):
    for num in range(hight):
        print('*' if num+star >= hight-1 else ' ', end='')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
def triangle(i, t=0):
    if i == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        print ' ' * ( t + 1 ) + '*' * ( i * 2 - 1 )
        return triangle( i - 1, t + 1 )
triangle(5)
```

Output:

```
* * * * * * * * *
   * * * * * * *
     * * * * *
       * * * 
         *
```

Comment: this may be the right answer but please explain how the code works, instead of just giving away the code for free

Answer (score 0):

```
def triangle(n):
    x = ('')
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        x += '*'
        print(' ' * (i + 1) + x)
```

Comment: This doesn't improve upon the answer that's already accepted