# left-hand triangle of x's

Tags: python-3.x

my question is almost identical to [How to make a triangle of x's in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908618/how-to-make-a-triangle-of-xs-in-python) but I want to know how to make it a left-hand edge triangle?

Answer (score 0):

Haha! How about this (Py3):

```
for i in range(1, 6):
  print('x'*i)
```